# How can i run several jquery clicks in a simpler way?

Tags: jquery, click

Hi I made this code but i think it is too messy and i dont quite work, can you help me?

I want to make it possible to the people at my work to checkin when they are there and when they are not.

When i know how to master the click function then i will try to add a jquery.post function so it can be saved on the page.

```js
var $plansHolders = $('#martinfri, #martinarbejd, #larsfri, #larsarbejd, #bentfri, #bentarbejd, #jacobfri, #jacobarbejd, #safri, #saarbejd, #steenfri, #steenarbejd, #dorthefri, #dorthearbejd, #jesperfri, #jesperarbejd, #hannefri, #hannearbejd').hide();
$('#martinfri').show();
$('.oversigt').click(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $plansHolders.hide();
  $(href).show();
});
```

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:50%">Name</td>
    <th style="width:50%">Status</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>Martin</td>
    <td>
<div id="martinfri" style="background-color:red;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#martinarbejd'>Off work</a></ul>
</div>
<div id="martinarbejd" style="background-color:lime;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#martinfri'>Working</a></ul>
</div>
</td> 
  </tr>

  <tr align="center">
    <td>Lars</td>
    <td>
<div id="larsfri" style="background-color:red;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#larsarbejd'>Off work</a></ul>
</div>
<div id="larsarbejd" style="background-color:lime;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#larsfri'>Working</a></ul>
</div>
</td> 
  </tr>

  <tr align="center">
    <td>Bent</td>
    <td>
<div id="bentfri" style="background-color:red;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#bentarbejd'>Off work</a></ul>
</div>
<div id="bentarbejd" style="background-color:lime;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#bentfri'>Working</a></ul>
</div>
</td> 
  </tr>

  <tr align="center">
    <td>Jacob</td>
    <td>
<div id="jacobfri" style="background-color:red;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#jacobarbejd'>Off work</a></ul>
</div>
<div id="jacobarbejd" style="background-color:lime;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#jacobfri'>Working</a></ul>
</div>
</td> 
  </tr>

  <tr align="center">
    <td>Steen-Allan</td>
    <td>
<div id="safri" style="background-color:red;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#saarbejd'>Off work</a></ul>
</div>
<div id="saarbejd" style="background-color:lime;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#safri'>Working</a></ul>
</div>
</td> 
  </tr>

  <tr align="center">
    <td>Steen</td>
    <td>
<div id="steenfri" style="background-color:red;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#steenarbejd'>Off work</a></ul>
</div>
<div id="steenarbejd" style="background-color:lime;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#steenfri'>Working</a></ul>
</div>
</td> 
  </tr>

  <tr align="center">
    <td>Dorthe</td>
    <td>
<div id="dorthefri" style="background-color:red;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#dorthearbejd'>Off work</a></ul>
</div>
<div id="dorthearbejd" style="background-color:lime;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#dorthefri'>Working</a></ul>
</div>
</td> 
  </tr>

  <tr align="center">
    <td>Jesper</td>
    <td>
<div id="jesperfri" style="background-color:red;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#jesperarbejd'>Off work</a></ul>
</div>
<div id="jesperarbejd" style="background-color:lime;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#jesperfri'>Working</a></ul>
</div>
</td> 
  </tr>

  <tr align="center">
    <td>Hanne</td>
    <td>
<div id="hannefri" style="background-color:red;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#hannearbejd'>Off work</a></ul>
</div>
<div id="hannearbejd" style="background-color:lime;">
<a class='oversigt' href='#hannefri'>Working</a></ul>
</div>
</td> 
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some invalid html code.
`<th>` closed with `</td>` instead of `</th>`
and many `</ul>` that are never opened.

As for the HTML, it would be a lot simpler.

Here's an example

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:50%">Name</th>
        <th style="width:50%">Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
        <td>Martin</td>
        <td id="martin">
            <a class='oversigt off-work btn' href='d'>Off work</a>
            <a class='oversigt working btn' href='#'>Working</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
        <td>Lars</td>
        <td>
            <a class='oversigt off-work btn' href='d'>Off work</a>
            <a class='oversigt working btn' href='#'>Working</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As for the CSS, you could use classes for the colors

```
.oversigt {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
.off-work {
    background:red;
}
.working {
    background:lime
}
```

Now, for the javascript

```
$('.oversigt').hide(); // I don't understand why you hide everything
$('#martin .off-work').show(); // and only show Martin
$('.oversigt').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //disables the click from executing the href
    var t = $(this); //better to save $(this) in a variable if you're going to use it more than once... not our case but good practice
    t.hide().siblings('.oversigt').show(); //the the item that's clicked, and show the one next it this one
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypymdsm6/2/)

Not sure if I answered your question, feel free to ask again.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it looks very good, i think the reason i hide everything is because i dont want to see both "working" and "not working" in the same cell at the same time, I just want to be able to switch between the two.

I want to ask you if you know how i can be able to do the same with "lars" as i can with "martin". I dont know how to make the option .off-work show for lars at the same time. :-)

Comment: If you look at my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ypymdsm6/2/) I suggest another way. Hope it helps.